# The progress of the operation delegated to the service

Tags: php, symfony, callback

In Symfony, I want to create a command that, when invoked, will run the method from the service - all operations will be performed there.
I would like the user to be able to see the progress of the operation.

So from the service methods I need to access the ProgressBar from the command.

On the Internet I found a solution consisting in sending a callback to the service that will operate on the progress bar.
Something like that:

```
// service method
public function update(\Closure $callback = null)
{
    $validCountryCodes = $this->countryRepository->findAll();

    $products = $this->productRepository->findWithInvalidCountryCode($validCountryCodes);

    foreach ($products as $product) {
        if ($callback) {
            $callback($product);
        }
        ...
    }
}

/**
 * command file
 */
public function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $progress = new ProgressBar($output, 50);

    $progress->start();

    $callback = function ($product) use ($progress) {
        $progress->advance();
    };
    $this->getContainer()->get('update.product.countries')->update($callback);
}
```

It works, but the problem is that in the service the operation is split into many methods.
The question is how to make the callback passed to the update method available to all methods in servie?

I could pass it as a parameter to each method I run, but that doesn't look very elegant...

Thank you in advance for your help.
Regards

Comment: Why can't Service::update store $callback as a property which can then be accessed from any other Service method that needs it?

Comment: @Cerad that's what I wants to get.
But I don't know how to pass $callback which is passed in the parameters of the update method to the global property of service class.

Comment: Hmmm.  Not entirely sure what you asking based on your posted code but coupling a service to a progress bar (even using a callback) seems a bit problematical.  Consider having your service emit a custom event and then have your command register itself as an event listener.

Comment: @Cerad Solution with the event listener solves the problem. Thank you!